# Propagation of signal to parent when using system

Tags: perl

I have written a wrapper script that starts another script using `system()`. The child script traps `SIGINT` and processes the exception internally. Therefore, it should not propagate the `SIGINT` to its parent when it exits.. However, in some cases the parent still receives the `SIGINT`. For example (`parent.pl`):

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX ();

my @data = (q(child.pl 'dummy'), q(child.pl), q(bash -c child.pl), q(sh -c child.pl));

for ( @data ) {
    say "Running command '$_'..";
    my $res = system $_;
    my $signal = $res & 127;
    my $rval = $res >> 8;
    say "Parent received return value: $rval";
    if ( $signal == POSIX::SIGINT ) {
        say "Parent received SIGINT";
    }
}
```

and `child.pl`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

eval {
    local $SIG{INT} = sub { die "Aborted by user.\n" };
    sleep 10;
};
if ( $@ ) {
    print "\n" . $@;
    exit 0;
}
say "Timed out..";
exit 1;
```

If I press <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> before the time out, the output looks like:

```
Running command 'child.pl 'dummy''..
^C
Aborted by user.
Parent received return value: 0
Parent received SIGINT
Running command 'child.pl'..
^C
Aborted by user.
Parent received return value: 0
Running command 'bash -c child.pl'..
^C
Aborted by user.
Parent received return value: 0
Running command 'sh -c child.pl'..
^C
Aborted by user.
Parent received return value: 0
Parent received SIGINT
```

So in the first and last case the parent receives the `SIGINT`, whereas for the second and third cases it does not.

What is the reason for this? And how can it be fixed such that the SIGINT is not propagated for the first and last case?

( I suspect it is related to the type of Shell, i.e. `sh` vs `bash` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's be aware of what is being executed.

```
system($shell_command)
```

is short for

```
system({ "/bin/sh" } "/bin/sh", "-c", $shell_command)
```

unless the shell command contains no shell meta-characters but whitespace, in which case

```
system($shell_command)
```

is short for

```
my @cmd = split(' ', $shell_command);
system({ $cmd[0] } @cmd)
```

As such,

```
system("child.pl 'dummy'")   is short for   system({ "/bin/sh" } "/bin/sh", "-c", "child.pl 'dummy'")
system("child.pl")           is short for   system({ "child.pl" } "child.pl")
system("bash -c child.pl")   is short for   system({ "bash" } "bash", "-c", "child.pl")
system("sh -c child.pl")     is short for   system({ "sh" } "sh", "-c", "child.pl")
```

Of note is that `bash` replaces itself with `child.pl` instead of spawning it in a separate process in this particular circumstance. That makes `child.pl` a direct child of `parent.pl` in the third case (just like the second case).

---

Second, let's be aware of what Ctrl-C does.

When Ctrl-C is pressed, the terminal sends SIGINT to every process that has that terminal as its controlling terminal. In other words, SIGINT is sent to every process of the session.

As you can see by adding `system("ps -o pid,ppid,pgrp,sid,cmd");` to `child.pl`, there are three or four processes in our session depending on the test case.

- `child.pl`: `child.pl` handles SIGINT. It isn't killed by it.
- The shell started by `parent.pl` in test cases 1 and 4: The shell is killed by SIGINT.
- `parent.pl`: `system` does the equivalent of `local $SIG{INT} = 'IGNORE';`, so it ignores SIGINT.
- The login shell that started `parent.pl`: It ignores SIGINT, but I'm not sure why. I'm guessing it's because it's an interactive shell.

---

So, this is what you are observing:

- When the (direct) child of `parent.pl` is `child.pl` [Test cases 2 and 3], the child (`child.pl`) does not die from SIGINT since it handles SIGINT.
- When the (direct) child of `parent.pl` is a shell [Test cases 1 and 4], the child (the shell) dies from SIGINT since non-interactive shells don't handle/ignore SIGINT.

Comment: Why would `system` replace `bash -c child.pl` with `perl child.pl` in the third case? And why does it not replace `sh -c child.pl` with `perl child.pl` in the fourth case? What could be the logic behind this?

Comment: Re "*Why would `system` replace `bash -c child.pl` with `perl child.pl` in the third case?*", It doesn't. Perl launches `bash`, which `exec`utes `child.pl`

Comment: Re "*why does it not replace `sh -c child.pl` with `perl child.pl` in the fourth case?*", Because it would be bad if it replaced what you asked to execute with something else.

Comment: Agree it would be bad.. but according to the output of `ps -o pid,ppid,pgrp,sid,cmd` it seemed like that happened

Comment: That has no relation on the initial program that was running in that process (which was `parent.pl`). The process's cmd went from `perl parent.pl` to `bash -c child.pl` (when the child created by `system` called `exec`), and then to `perl child.pl` (when `bash` called `exec`).

Comment: So at startup time, whenever the `perl` executable determines that its parent is `/bin/bash` or `bash` it does not start itself in a new process, but somehow replaces the parent `bash` using `exec`? Is this correct? And why is it done?

Comment: No, bash uses exec. You know that exec doesn't create a process, right? It changes what the current process executes.