# Return value from system() when using SIGINT default handler

Tags: bash, perl, signals, sh

I am experiencing some strange return values from `system()` when a child process receives a SIGINT from the terminal. To explain, from a Perl script `parent.pl` I used `system()` to run another Perl script as a child process, but I also needed to run the child through the shell, so I used the `system 'sh', '-c', ...` form.. So the parent of the child became the `sh` process and the parent of the `sh` process became `parent.pl`. Also, to avoid having the `sh` process receiving the `SIGINT` signal, I trapped it.

For example, `parent.pl`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

for (1..3) {
    my $res = system 'sh', '-c', "trap '' INT; child$_.pl";
    say "Parent received return value: " . ($res >> 8);
}
```

where `child1.pl`:

```
local $SIG{INT} = "DEFAULT";
sleep 10;
say "Child timed out..";
exit 1;
```

`child2.pl`:

```
local $SIG{INT} = sub { die };
sleep 10;
say "Child timed out..";
exit 1;
```

and `child3.pl` is:

```
eval {
    local $SIG{INT} = sub { die };
    sleep 10;
};
if ( $@ ) {
    print $@;
    exit 2;
}
say "Child timed out..";
exit 0;
```

If I run `parent.pl` (from the command line) and press CTRL-C to abort each child process, the output is:

```
^CParent received return value: 130
^CDied at ./child2.pl line 7.
Parent received return value: 4
^CDied at ./child3.pl line 8.
Parent received return value: 2
```

Now, I would like to know why I get a return value of 130 for case 1, and a return value of 4 for case 2.

Also, it would be nice to know exactly what the `"DEFAULT"` signal handler does in this case.

Note: the same values are returned if I replace `sh` with `bash` ( and trap `SIGINT` instead of `INT` in `bash` ).

See also:

- [Propagation of signal to parent when using system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795478/propagation-of-signal-to-parent-when-using-system)
- [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html)
- Chapter 15, in [Programming Perl, 4th Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is very similar to [Propagation of signal to parent when using system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34795478/2766176) that you asked earlier.

From my bash docs:

> When a command terminates on a fatal signal N, bash uses the value of 128+N as the exit status.

SIGINT is typically 2, so 128 + 2 give you 130.

Perl's [die](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) figures out its exit code by inspecting `$!` or `$?` for an uncaught exception (so, not the case where you use `eval`):

```
exit $! if $!;              # errno
exit $? >> 8 if $? >> 8;    # child exit status
exit 255;                   # last resort
```

Notice that in this case, Perl exits with the value as is, not shifted up 8 bits.

The errno value happens to be 4 (see [errno.h](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno)). The `$!` variable is a dualvar with different string and numeric values. Use it numerically (like adding zero) to get the number side:

```
use v5.10;

local $SIG{INT}=sub{
    say "numeric errno is ", $!+0;
    die
    };
sleep 10;
print q(timed out);
exit 1;
```

This prints:

```
$ bash -c "perl errno.pl"
^Cnumeric errno is 4
Died at errno.pl line 6.
$ echo $?
4
```

Comment: `errno` 4 is `EINTR`, "Interrupted system call". `sleep` set this when it the signal came in.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your questions out of order:

> Also, it would be nice to know exactly what the "DEFAULT" signal handler does in this case.

Setting the handler for a given signal to `"DEFAULT"` affirms or restores the default signal handler for the given signal, whose action depends on the signal.  Details are available from [the signal(7) manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).  The default handler for `SIGINT` terminates the process.

> Now, I would like to know why I get a return value of 130 for case 1, and a return value of 4 for case 2.

Your child1 explicitly sets the default handler for `SIGINT`, so that signal causes it to terminate abnormally.  *Such a process has no exit code* in the conventional sense.  The shell also receives the `SIGINT`, but it traps and ignores it.  The exit status it reports for the child process (and therefore for itself) reflects the signal (number 2) that killed the child.

Your other two child processes, on the other hand, *catch* `SIGINT` and terminate normally in response.  These do produce exit codes, which the shell passes on to you (after trapping and ignoring the `SIGINT`).  [The documentation for `die()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) describes how the exit code is determined in this case, but the bottom line is that if you want to exit with a specific code then you should use `exit` instead of `die`.