# Perl detects wrong exit code from fork/exec if child signalled

Tags: c++, linux, perl

I fork/exec a C++ program from perl and want to detect the exit status of the child (in particular when the child exits because of a segfault)

The perl behavior is inconsistent depending on whether the child calls `exit()`, is signalled externally, or actually encounters a segfault.

From the shell, the exit code from the C++ is always correct. eg. `echo $?` matches what the program did.

From perl, the exit code detected by perl is correct only if `exit()` was called. If the program exits due to a signal or segfault the exit code detected by perl is always 0.

Why?

I'd like to consistently get the exit code of the C++ program in the perl script.

perl 5.10.1, Centos 6 32-bit, g++ 4.8.2

**Test Results**

- Actual Segfault (`boom` enabled): `Perl Complete: 27322 exited (exit
  0, sig 11, core 0)`
- a.out Killed via `kill -11 <pid>`: `Perl Complete: 27248 exited (exit 0,
  sig 11, core 0)`
- a.out completes, calls `exit(139)`: `Perl Complete: 27237 exited (exit 139, sig 0, core 0)`

Calling `a.out` from the shell always shows the correct exit code in all three of the above cases.

**C++ A.OUT**

(comment out `boom` depending on the test)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char  **argv)
{
    printf("Started with PID %d\n", getpid());

    int d = 1;
    if (argc > 1)
        d = atoi(argv[1]);

    int loops = 10;
    while(loops-- > 0)
    {
        printf("Ping\n");
        sleep(1);
    }

    printf("MAKE SEGFAULT\n");
    int boom = *(int*)0x00;

    printf("exit with %d\n", d);
    exit(d);
}
```

**PERL**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";

my $fullprocname = "./a.out 139";
my $childPID = fork();

if ($childPID == 0)        # child
{
    open(STDERR, ">&SAVEERR");  # restore stderr
    $< = $>;                    # set real to effective uid, otherwise
                                # some env variables not passed in ??
    exec ($fullprocname) or die "exec $fullprocname failed: $!\n"; 
}
else                       # parent
{
    print("DVMon.pl: Forked $childPID for $fullprocname\n");
}

print("Waiting for child process\n");
my $child = wait();

my $exitStatus = $? >> 8;   # similar to WEXITSTATUS
my $termSig    = $? & 127;  # similar to WTERMSIG
my $coreDump   = $? & 128;  # similar to WCOREDUMP

my $msg = "$childPID exited (exit $exitStatus, sig $termSig, core $coreDump)";
print("Perl Complete: $msg\n");
```

Comment: What happens if you run your C code (can't see where the C++ code is) with a different value other than 139?

Comment: Trying with SIGUSR1 (10) ends up with the same behavior.

Comment: I doubt the exitcode is meaningful in case of a signal.

Comment: @PerlDuck actually it should 128+signal number

Comment: @Danny no, I meant what happens if you run the C code with a number like 16 rather than using a different signal.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Well, `$?` contains 139 (for SIG11) and by right-shifting by 8 you end up with rc=0 and sig=11. I don't see a problem here. Do you expect `$?>>8` also to be 139?

Comment: @PerlDuck I meant $? should be 139

Comment: Chris, I can't find the reference but read that signalled processes should exit not with zero but with the signal number. Could be wrong on that - your comment makes sense. Will keep looking for the reference.  (and it is C++, but trimmed to the smallest reproducible fragment)

Comment: If it were C++ you'd be using `cout` not `printf` and including "iostream" not "stdio.h"

Comment: Re "*Perl detects wrong exit code from fork/exec if child signalled*", What do you mean? Are you saying you aren't getting the values you showed undef "Test Results"?

Comment: See also [Return value from system() when using SIGINT default handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34963555/2173773)

Answer (score 2):

This is working as designed. In the shell, there are two ways to get an exit code of 139 from a command.

1. The command makes the system call `exit(139)`
2. The command is terminated with signal 11

But POSIX-y systems can distinguish between these two events, and Perl hooks into these methods to make its `$?` variable more informative than what the shell will provide.

Answer (score 1):

> *If the program exits due to a signal or segfault the exit code detected by perl is always 0. Why?*

It never reached `exit`, so `WEXITSTATUS` is meaningless, so the system sets it to zero.

The values Perl show are the values provided by the system, and they are the values should be expecting. You will get the same results in C as you did in Perl, for example.

When a process is killed by a signal, the system provides that information. `sh`, on the other, doesn't provide that information. If you're wondering why the `sh`'s `$?` is different than Perl's `$?`, it's because the shell mangles the exit code into 8 bits as follows:

```
 $?<sh> = ( $?<real> & 0x7F ) ? ( $?<real> | 0x80 ) : ( $?<real> >> 8 );
```