# CTRL+C and Perl's system() function - script not getting interrupted

Tags: linux, perl

I have a Perl script that starts some programs using the `system()` function, in sequential order. While the script is running and a program run is ongoing, I type CTRL + C. I expect the program to terminate (which happens), but I would also expect the script to terminate (which doesn't happen).

I've built a minimum working example. Here's the Perl script:

```
#!/bin/env perl


sub run_the_test {
  local($name, $_) = @_;

  print "Starting $name\n";
  return system("program.bash $name");
}


&run_the_test("test1");
&run_the_test("test2");
&run_the_test("test3");
```

and here's the external "program":

```
#!/bin/env bash

echo "Started $1"
sleep 3
echo "Finished $1"
```

I started the script and issued a CTRL + Z. I then did a `ps -o pid,pgrp,cmd` to list the process info. I can see that the script, the bash shell it invokes and the sleep command all belong to the same process group. While the `sleep` is executing I would also expect that to be the foreground process group. I've read up a bit on Linux, signals and the terminal and found that CTRL + C should send an interrupt to the entire foreground process group, thus terminating the script as well.

I've also tried using `exec()` instead of `system()`. This way the script does stop when triggering CTRL + C, but it doesn't run past *test1*.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on here?

Comment: "*This way the script does stop when triggering CTRL + C*" - No, this way the script is gone by the time your program starts. `exec` only returns if it fails.

Comment: Why are you writing perl4-style code? It's not 1993 anymore; please `use strict;` and `use warnings;` and don't call subs with `&`.

Comment: See also [Perl forward SIGINT to parent process from `system` command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34457955/2173773) and [Propagation of signal to parent when using system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34795478/2173773)

Comment: @melpomene It's a snippet of some legacy Perl script I have that I stripped down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's good that you've investigated and understood the process groups. Explaining those is usually the hard part of a question like this. So you know that the interrupt signal `SIGINT` is supposed to be sent to all processes in the process group, including your `perl` process.

But `SIGINT` isn't always fatal. It can be caught or ignored. The `system()` function ignores `SIGINT` while the child process is running. This feature makes it possible for you to interrupt a child process that has gone bad, without killing the parent too.

In perlfunc, the description of `system()` says:

> Since "SIGINT" and "SIGQUIT" are ignored during the execution of
>   "system", if you expect your program to terminate on receipt of
>   these signals you will need to arrange to do so yourself based on
>   the return value.
>
> ```
> @args = ("command", "arg1", "arg2");
> system(@args) == 0
>     or die "system @args failed: $?"
> ```

This is what you need to do. Check the return value of `system()`, and take whatever action you think is appropriate when a child process fails. If you want to distinguish `SIGINT` from other kinds of failures, the next paragraph in perlfunc will help:

> If you'd like to manually inspect "system"'s failure, you can check
>   all possible failure modes by inspecting $? like this:
>
> ```
> if ($? == -1) {
>     print "failed to execute: $!\n";
> }
> elsif ($? & 127) {
>     printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
>         ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
> }
> else {
>     printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
> }
> ```

For example you could do this in `run_the_test`:

```
my $r = system("program.bash $name");
die "Test interrupted, giving up" if ($? & 127) == 2;
return $r;
```

Comment: If you don't want to hardcode `2`, you can `use POSIX qw(SIGINT);` to import a `SIGINT` constant.

Comment: Another option is to use `fork` and `exec` to launch the child process instead of `system`.

Comment: @salva I read in the description of `system()` that it's equivalent to a `fork()`, `exec()` and `wait()` call.

Comment: @TudorTimi that's a broad outline of what `system()` does. It's good enough to understand the relationship between the processes. It omits details like signal manipulation. The point of salva's comment is if you implement a `system()`-like function yourself, you can change the details.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem, using system and piping. CTRL-C would not work.
Following solved it:

use sigtrap qw/die normal-signals/;